# C++ Directly calling a vector element's function (Eclipse CDT bug?)

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm getting a weird error when trying to call a vector element's function. For example, if I do this

[image: error]

However it works fine if I do this:

[image: no error]

The code runs fine in Visual Studio, so is this a bug with Eclipse CDT?

P.S. ignore the [endl bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674598/eclipse-complains-invalid-overload-of-endl-but-code-does-compile)

EDIT:
Compiler error from Visual C++

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\Include\vector(1494) : error C2528: '_Ptr' : pointer to reference is illegal
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\Include\vector(1658) : error C2528: '_Pval' : pointer to reference is illegal
```

Compiler error from MinGW

```
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h:87:68: error: using invalid field 'std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Vector_impl::_M_finish'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h:87:68: error: using invalid field 'std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Vector_impl::_M_end_of_storage'
```

Note that it compiles fine in Visual Studio

EDIT 2:

ok so...now it works for some reason. Yes I was wrong for choosing the `back()` method as an example, because it was failing for any method I tried. But for some reason, after a couple days of this problem, Eclipse fixed itself, and now the only error message I get from this code is

```
..\src\main.cpp:48:21: error: 'class std::basic_string<char>' has no member named 'back'
```

I wouldn't be surprised if the issue came back though, but I guess it really is a problem with Eclipse, either with the IDE itself or with my environment/linker settings

Comment: In the second example, try `string const& test = string[0];` instead, and see if that still works. If so, the problem is (probably) with the type inferred for `strings[0]` in the first example. If it stops working, the problem is with finding a `back` method for `const` strings (which is odd, since [`back` has a `const` overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/back)).

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear, the second example works fine, I'm using it to emphasize that the problem is with calling a vector element directly, not with any other part of my code

Comment: Are you getting a compiler error, or is it just Eclipse's Codan tool that's showing the red squiggles? If it's the latter, there may not be much you can do about it, Googling for that will reveal that you're not the first one to see false errors reported by Codan.

Comment: Are you claiming the first code doesn't *compile* with (I'm assuming clang++ or g++), or just that the Eclipse CDT bitches about their faux intellisense not working as well as Visual Studio's?

Comment: sorry, its a compiler error. See my edit

Comment: Did you include the right headers? Do you have `using std::vector` etc?

Comment: yes, otherwise I would have gotten a different error

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `std::basic_string::back` is new in C++11. So unless you compile in C++11 mode (using `-std=c++11` for gcc, for example), it's not going to compile. Here's the complete test code I used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> strings;
    strings.push_back("test");
    std::cout << strings[0].back() << '\n';
}
```

So, you'd have to configure your Eclipse to use C++11 mode, also.

Comment: this wasn't the issue, I was just using that method as an example for simplicity. I actually wasn't able to call any method